# UE4 Blueprint Interface in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, yui

I am attemping to make a graph like interface in javascript (probably utilizing D3.js or YUI), to mimic (somewhat) the interface of Unreal Engine 4's blueprint editor. It is showcased here:

[UE4 Blueprint Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5pIrpI7py8)

Is there any library in javascript that basically does this , or if not , which library would you recommend me to study to create this.

When I say it needs to be like that, I don't mean the EXACT look and feel, just the general Node 1 has x inputs y outputs, connect output 2 to input 3 of node 2, etc.. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [NoFlo](http://noflojs.org/) would help you.. It's a GUI for [FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).

Comment: I like the NoFlo UI, that is essentially what I am trying to make, after a short evaluation of their github repo for the UI I realized they are utilizing polymer, perhaps that is the weapon of choice to create my UI.

Comment: What did you end up using for this? I want to do similar! Thanks